# Why Is google-Chrome and Chromium no longer runs in Ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, chromium

Does not matter if I install Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit or Ubuntu 14.04-2, Chrome and also Chromium installs, but will no longer open when using a Non-Proprietary Nvidia driver. Chromium And Google-Chrome-Stable will only run using the Nouveau driver. What is the problem?  How Can I continue to use Ubuntu if I cannot run my Nvidia card properly and can not use Chromium? And why am I the only one it seems having this issue?  Never in my life have I had this type of trouble before.

Answer (score 1):

Now you cannot run google-chrome as root user on updated versions, To run Google Chrome as standard user (while Logged in as Root)

open terminal and type:

`adduser -u chromeuser` OR `useradd -m chromeuser`

To run google chrome use command:

`gksu -u chromeuser google-chrome` OR `sux chromeuser google-chrome`

If you don't want to run it from Terminal then add chrome in taskbar and then right-click on it, select properties and add the above command in the command parameter.